# How to redirect the user to a custom page when user click "Connect to QuickBooks" button?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

So Intuit charges for each active connections to QuickBooks. Therefore, I want to restrict the  QuickBooks functionality in my application to premium users only.

Ideally when any user clicks the "Connect to QuickBooks" button and my RequestOAuthToken http handler is called, I want to check if the user is allowed to use QuickBooks. If that is the case, then the normal OAuth flow continue. If the user is NOT allowed, then I want to redirect the user to the upgrade page of my app.

Given that the "Connect to QuickBooks" button opens a new window (at least on desktop, I haven't tried on phone/tablets), the window should get closed, and the main window (my app) should redirect the user to the right page. And actually this is exactly what happens if the normal OAuth flow completes.

Now, I have tried a few different approaches but I couldn't get it working.

1) In my RequestOAuthToken, return a HTTP redirect to the plan page

2) In my RequestOAuthToken, return an html page with javascript logic to redirect to page

3) In my RequestOAuthToken, return HTTP redirect to a page with javascript logic to redirect to page

4) I haven't tried that one but could I somehow intercept the javascript click handler on the Intuit button. I'm not sure if that is an accepted practice.

Here is the piece a javascript I grabbed from the .Net sample:

```
try
{
    var parentlocation = window.parent.opener.location.hostname;
    var currentlocation = window.location.hostname;
    if (parentlocation != currentlocation)
    {
        window.location = plansUrl;
    }
    else
    {
        window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;
        window.close();
    }
}
catch (e)
{
    window.location = plansUrl;
}
```

Help me out please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to do exactly what you're asking, but you can probably come close by taking a different approach.

Rather than trying to redirect them *after* they click the button, why not try to redirect them *before* they click it? e.g. when they try to get to the page that has the "Connect to QuickBooks" button it, check if they are a premium user there, and redirect them if they are not.

I don't think you'll be able to redirect them *after* they click the button because once they click that button, they get kicked over to Intuit's website and it's beyond your control at that point.

Comment: The thing is, I'd like have the quickbooks button to appear on every page at the top right corner, and I'd also like to be able to use the intuit widget, which has the right look and feel.

Comment: Have you asked Intuit about doing this? They tend to be pretty strict (understandably so) about how their UI components work (because they're trying to maintain a consistent UI experience across all Intuit-integrated apps). I think it's unlikely that they'll allow you to use their widgets, but change the behavior of them...

Comment: Could you just use a link which says "Connect to QuickBooks" on every page instead, which then either brings you to a page with the "Connect to QuickBooks" button, or brings you to the "upgrade" page if you're not a premium user?

Comment: Clement, You would need to follow Keith's approach here. You cannot alter the functionality of the button. You could instead look up the users current status, and if they are not a premier user then you would hide the connect button and instead replace it with a message to prompt the user to upgrade before they can connect to quickbooks.

Answer (score 2):

Clement, Keith has provided the answer we would want you to pursue.  You may not alter the behavior of the Connect To QuickBooks button.  It must be used as described in our documentation.  Providing a link to a page that shows the Connect To QuickBooks buttons for your premium users and an upgrade message to non-premium users is the way to go.

I highly recommend that you visit http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0010_Getting_Started/0040_Publishing_Your_App and review all of the documentation there.  If you develop with our guidelines and requirements in mind it will speed up the review process.

Tony Purmal
Developer Relations Engineer
Intuit Partner Platform